# Create namespace and secret, do patch only if not existing

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

In my CI I'm running a `helm upgrade` command to release an app.
But if it is a non existing app, I have to create the namespace, a secret and patch the serviceaccount. So I come up with this:

```
kubectl create namespace ${namespace} --dry-run=client -o yaml | kubectl apply -f -
kubectl create secret docker-registry gitlab-registry --namespace ${namespace} --docker-server="\${CI_REGISTRY}" --docker-username="\${CI_DEPLOY_USER}" --docker-password="\${CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}" --docker-email="\${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}" -o yaml --dry-run=client | kubectl apply -f -
kubectl patch serviceaccount default -p '{"imagePullSecrets":[{"name":"gitlab-registry"}]}' --namespace ${namespace}
```

This is working, but I think it is not the perfect way as these three steps should only be done once.
: Only if app/namespace/secret is not existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helm provides the `--create-namespace` switch that will create the namespace of the release if it does not already exist.

The secret can be added in your helm chart and you can pass the variables (`CI_REGISTRY`, `CI_DEPLOY_USER`, etc.) in as helm chart values either as `--set` values or via the `values.yaml` file and using `--values`

The service account patching you can do as a post-install and/or a post-upgrade job (https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/)